# IIS 5.1 + ASP .NET MVC 3 + Image not loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, iis

I am developping a web application by using the ASP .NET MVC 3 framework.
I am using Windows XP Professional on my computer.
I have decided to execute my web application via my IIS 5.1 local server during the development.

First I have installed IIS 5.1.
Then I have created a virtual directory under the default web site for my web application.
Then I have executed the following command line :

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Then I have added the following extension mapping to my virtual directory :

- Executable : C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
- Extension : .*
- Option "Check file existence" unchecked.

For information here is my RegisterRoutes method written in my Global.asax.cs file :

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Accueil", action = "Accueil", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Default parameters
    );
}
```

When I launch my web application via Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode then I can load one my view with success.
But I noticed that an image was not loaded.
Here is the img tag containing the image :

```
<img src="../../../Content/images/Valider_064.png" alt="Valider" />
```

Here is a piece of my web application folder tree :

- ActivitesHtml5 [FOLDER] : Root of web application

  - Content [FOLDER]

    - images [FOLDER]

      - Valider_064.png [FILE]
  - Controller [FOLDER]

    - ConnexionController.cs [FILE] : Contains the action method to generate my view.
  - Views [FOLDER]

    - Connexion [FOLDER]

      - Connexion [FOLDER]

        - Connexion.cshtml [FILE] : Razor file of my view.

Does someone know why my image is not correctly loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using url helpers instead of hardcoding your urls:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Valider_064.png")" alt="Valider" />
```

Also I would totally recommend you to stay away from IIS 5.1 especially if your target deployment server for the application will be IIS 7.0+. Cassini or IIS Express are much better alternatives and are directly integrated into Visual Studio.